# Regexp / htaccess rewrite fun

Tags: regex, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a long list of URLs from an old site structure that I need to redirect using RedirectMatch to new URLs on the same domain. The trick is that the old (source) URLs contain a bunch of messy variables. That's not a problem, right? I just put in place some sweet little Regexp statements to handle those variables. That's what I did, and it matches the variables correctly. Sweet!

The problem comes with the second part of the RedirectMatch statement - the destination. RedirectMatch is correctly resolving the old URLs to the new URLs, except that the old variables are appended to the new URL. I want to keep the redirects, but have the destination URL not contain the variables. Here is my code:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/Shop/Category1/Category2/(.*)$ http://www.website.com/garage.html
```

Actual Redirect URL:

```
http://www.website.com/garage.html?launch_pg=itemZoomView&launch_sel=1009152&launch_pg_sp=true&title=Pig+Waste+Can
```

Can anybody point me to what I am doing wrong here? I just want to get rid of those crummy old variables and start fresh.

Answer (score 1):

If by "variables" you mean query string (the `launch_pg=itemZoomView&launch_sel=1009152&launch_pg_sp=true&title=Pig+Waste+Can` part of your destination URL example), then use this redirect rule:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/Shop/Category1/Category2/(.*)$ http://www.website.com/garage.html?
```

The only difference -- the `?` at the end of new URL. This stops old query string from being copied over as we telling Apache that new URL will have this **empty** query string.

---

If you can use **mod_rewrite**, here is the rule:

```
# Activate Rewrite Engine
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

# the rewrite rule
RewriteRule ^Shop/Category1/Category2/(.*)$ http://www.website.com/garage.html? [R=301,L]
```

This definitely will redirect with empty query string.

Comment: Yes, I actually came across that in my ongoing research since this post, and gave it a whirl. The result is that the extra "?" is just appended to the beginning of the variables, such as: http://www.website.com/garage.html??launch_pg=itemZoomView&launch_sel=1009152&launch_pg_sp=true&title=Pig+Waste+Can

Comment: @Tela -- I do not know what have you done -- but that should not work like that. The code I have provided works 100% -- I run few websites that utilizes similar code with no issues on Apache 2.2.17.

Comment: @Tela I have added mod_rewrite powered redirect rule which does the same job.

Comment: I agree, this behavior is not what I would expect on my end. I had actually created the same RewriteRule as you have above and that did not work either. I move that RewriteRule up in the htaccess as well, since my site uses Magento and that includes some exclusions such as !l, !d, !f. No luck - it still 404s.

Comment: @Tela Please show your full htaccess (update your question). The rule itself is working 100% (nearly all of my rep on this site coming from answering this type of questions).

Comment: I actually solved the issue. The rule was working. There were the following statements above my RewriteRule that were negating the rule:RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l